# Google map not working with java (JSF) application using primefaces?

Tags: java, google-maps, jsf, primefaces

google map not displaying with java application.. here is my code..
I am using  **xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"** my code to display google map as followed..

```
< p:gmap id="gMapClinics" center="36.890257,30.707417" zoom="2" type="terrain" model="#{searchController.advancedModel}"  style="width:100%;height:600px;  margin-top: 60px;"><p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{searchController.onMarkerSelect}" />
                    < p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow" >
                        < p:outputPanel style="text-align: center; display: block; margin: auto" >
                            < p:graphicImage name="/images/islamabad.png" height="150" />
                            < br />
                            < h:outputText value="#{searchController.marker.title}" />
                        < /p:outputPanel>
                    < /p:gmapInfoWindow>
                < /p:gmap>
```

Comment: Please format your code. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have terminated the `<p:gmap>` before it's nested components and you haven't terminated the `<p:ajax>` tag below.

Fix it like this:

```
<p:gmap id="gMapClinics" center="36.890257,30.707417" 
         zoom="2" type="terrain" model="#{searchController.advancedModel}"  
         style="width:100%;height:600px;  margin-top: 60px;">
    <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{searchController.onMarkerSelect}" />
    <p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow" >
        <p:outputPanel style="text-align: center; display: block; margin: auto" >
            <p:graphicImage name="/images/islamabad.png" height="150" />
            <br />
            <h:outputText value="#{searchController.marker.title}" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:gmapInfoWindow>
</p:gmap>
```